# getting custom dependency property

Tags: silverlight, reflection, dependency-properties

I have a control which contains my custom dependencyproperty like this:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseEnterColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MouseEnterColor", typeof (Color), typeof (SCADAPolyline), new PropertyMetadata(default(Color)));

        public Color MouseEnterColor
        {
            get { return (Color) GetValue(MouseEnterColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MouseEnterColorProperty, value); }
        }
```

Its weird problem.I am using reflection to get my property for setting new value.But cant get my property.I tried every possibility from type.GetFields()

```
 FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(name, BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

or 

 fieldInfo = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                          .Where(p => p.FieldType.Equals(typeof(DependencyProperty)) && p.Name==name).FirstOrDefault();
```

sounds like my property is missing.I cant access and this problem makes me so angry.
How can i solve this problem any ideas? I am using silverlight 5.0

Comment: Have you debugged what is `name`? And why don't you try to get the non static `MouseEnterColor` wrapper ?

Comment: yes,I checked its name correct.

Comment: +1 for good description & code. Always helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Dependency Property is not a Field. It is not a part of the class definition in the usual sense.

Behind the scenes it is stored in a collection of Dependency Properties.

Try this example [from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c) as a guide on how to access them:

```
    public static class DependencyObjectHelper
    {
        public static List<DependencyProperty> GetDependencyProperties(Object element)
        {
            List<DependencyProperty> properties = new List<DependencyProperty>();
            MarkupObject markupObject = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(element);
            if (markupObject != null)
            {
                foreach (MarkupProperty mp in markupObject.Properties)
                {
                    if (mp.DependencyProperty != null)
                    {
                        properties.Add(mp.DependencyProperty);
                    }
                }
            }

            return properties;
        }
```